# Add / update column from a query SELECT? SQL

Tags: sql

I'm quite a novice on this and I don't know if I will explain myself well. I am trying to do an exercise in SQL in which asks me to update the data in an "X" table from other data in a "Y" table. The problem is that it is not about updating table X exactly like the data in table Y. I put the statement and my tables:

Update the "numJocs" field (number of games) for all platforms, depending on the number of games each of the platforms in the GAMES table has.

PLATFORM table:

[image: platform table]

where: "nom" is name.

GAMES table:

[image: games table]

where: "nom" is name, "preu" is price, "idPlataforma" is idPlatform and "codiTenda" is storeCode, but only idPlataforma interested for this exercise.

If I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(games.idPlataforma)
FROM games
GROUP BY (games.idPlataforma)
```

I can see how many games there are for each platform. The result would be:

```
count(games.idPlataforma)
__________________________
2
1
2
2
```

I would like to be able to put this result in the PLATFORM table, column "numJocs". But I don't know how to do it ... I also don't want to put it manually, that is, a "2" in a row "1", etc ... but I would like to be able to make a query and add that query in the column that I have to fill in. He tried to do a thousand things, but nothing ... Any help?

Thanks!!

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images (or links to images.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for one time update you can use below query

```
update Product P
INNER JOIN (
SELECT games.idPlataforma, COUNT(games.idPlataforma) as cnt
FROM games
GROUP BY games.idPlataforma
) x ON P.id= x.idPlataforma
SET P.numJocs= x.cnt
```

For the next time on every entry of new game you have a update numJocs

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!
What I did in 27 lines of code is reduced by only 7.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 2 tables, table 1 and table 2:

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

You could insert new values into table 1, based on table 2 by doing the following:

```sql
insert  into Table1(number,CFG) select ITEM,results from Table2
```

Which has the following result in table 1:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any database should support the syntax using a correlated subquery:

```
update platforms
    set numjocs = (select count(*)
                   from games g
                   where g.idPlatforms = platforms.id
                  );
```

I would caution you though about storing this value in the table.  It will be immediately out of data if the `platforms` table changes.  If you want to keep it in synch, then you need to create triggers -- and this is all rather complicated.

Rather, calculate the data on the fly:

```
select p.*,
       (select count(*)
        from games g
        where g.idPlatforms = platforms.id
       ) as numjocs
from platforms p ;
```

You can put this in a view if you like.  Many databases support *materialized views* where the results of the view are stored in a "table" and the table is kept up-to-date with the underlying data.